# Translation UnityScript to C#: GetComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm working to translate a Unity project originally in UnityScript to C#. I already have translated a good part of the project, but I'm confronted with some problems:

```
characterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
```

Throws the error:

```
'UnityEngine.CharacterController' is a type but is used as a variable.
The overloaded method that best suits 'UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent (string)' 
has invalid arguments
```

And the second error:

```
GetComponent.<Animation>().Stop();
```

Throws the error:

```
Only a subpoena, call, increment, and decrement, and an expectation of new object expressions 
can be used as instruction.
```

So It's only errors linked with GetComponent, but in UnityScript it's working fine. How to deal with that in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
characterController = GetComponent(CharacterController);
```

Should be called with the generic version, in C#:

```
characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
```

Regarding the other line, you have an extra dot in the middle. Should be:

```
GetComponent<Animation>().Stop();
```

(not sure if you have to specify also the name of the particular animation to stop).

Comment: Thanks for your help ! It's working :) I have some others questions to ask you, It is possible ?

Comment: @PokeRwOw: Happy that's working for you! If you have other questions, I suggest you to open new posts here, so that a lot of people could potentially help you. Cheers.